# Is it possible to pass an html attribute in an ngClass?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, svg, attributes, ionic4

I am using Ionic and I have an svg path that looks like this in myComponent.html file:

```
 <path id="US" (click)="countryNameDetails($event)" title="United States" [ngClass]="{'BEEN' : array.indexOf('United States') !== -1, 'NOTBEEN' : array.indexOf('United States) === -1 }".../>
```

the path changes CSS classes based on whether or not a word is in my array. This word is basically the same as the title for each path and i dont want to keep writing out the title name. Is there anyway that i can pass the title attribute in the path in my ngClass...Ive tried everything i could think of!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a template reference variable to your svg path and access the title attribute.

```
<path
  title="United States"
  [ngClass]="{'BEEN': array.indexOf(path.title) !== -1, 'NOTBEEN': array.indexOf(path.title) === -1 }"
  #path
/>
```

I'd prefer this syntax:

```
<path
  title="United States"
  [ngClass]="array.includes(path.title) ? 'been' : 'not-been'"
  #path
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but it still does not work. It doesnt throw any errors but  doesnt find the title

Comment: It definitely worked in my test app. Can you provide a stackblitz?